# Как получить кол-во пользователей с определенной ролью discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь определить сколько участников имеют роль. Делаю так:

```
guild = ctx.guild
for role in guild.roles:
    if role.name.startswith("#"):
        await ctx.send(f"{role.name}\n{role.members}")
```

Но в ответ получаю:

```
#9DE42E
[]
```

Хотя роль присутствует и у меня и у ещё некоторых пользователей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно импортировать `utlis` из библиотеки `discord` и с его помощью получать объект роли по id.

**Делается это так:**

1. Имортируем модуль `utlis` из дискорда: `from discord import utils`
2. Получаем объект роли через `utils.get()`. Первым аргументом передается список ролей сервера, вторым - id конкретной роли. `role = utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = roleID)`

**Польный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    roleID = # id нужной роли, можно получить 
             # правым кликом на роль > Копировать ID (Нужен режим разработчика)

    role = utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = roleID)
    print(f'Список пользователей для роли "{role.name}"\n')
    number = 0
    for member in role.members:
        number += 1
        print(f'№: {number}\nName: {member.name}\nID: {member.id}\nDiscriminator: {member.discriminator}\nStatus: {member.status}\n')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```